# Get Struct from child class and use in main class

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

Here is the issue with my code

I got a parent class `Shape` and a child class `Square`

```
struct Point
{
    int x,y;
};

class Shape
{
private:
    string name;

public:
    void setName(string);
    string getName();
    virtual void setVerticlePoint() { };
    virtual Point getVerticlePoint();
};
```

Below is Square.cpp

```
class Square: public Shape
{
private:
    Point verticlePoint[4];

public:
    int noOfVerticles() const { return 5; }
    void setVerticlePoint();
    Point getVerticlePoint();
};

void Square::setVerticlePoint()
{
    int xData,yData;

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter x-ordinate of pt." << i << " :";
        cin > xData;
        cout << "Please enter y-ordinate of pt." << i << " :";
        cin >> yData;
        verticlePoint[i]->x = xData;
        verticlePoint[i]->y = yData;
    }
}
```

So at main.cpp , i did this

```
int main()
{
    Shape *point[5];
    Point vertic`lePoint;
    Square *cro = new Square();

    // some codes in between

    // now i prompt for verticle point

    shape[0] = squr;

    //assuming myShape & myType is some string value
    shape[0]->setName(myShape);
    shape[0].setType(myType);

    //here i will be prompt to key in 4 times of X & y Ordinate of the verticle point
    shape[0]->setVerticlePoint();

    //Now the issue is i need to retrieve back my verticle point that i store in shape[0].

    //here no issue
    cout << "Get Name: " << shape[0]->getName() << endl;
    cout << "Get Data:"  << shape[0]->getType() << endl;
    //the top 2 works

    //this is the issue
    verticlePoint = shape[0]->getVerticlePoint();
    cout << sizeof(verticlePoint);
    //it output as size 8 , no matter which shape i use, i got other shapes with different verticle point.

    return 0;
}
```

Issue is :

How do i retrieve the `verticlePoint[array]` (e.g for square is `verticlePoint[4]`, how do i retrieve the Point into a variable in main class, and then use a for loop to call out the `x,y` of `shape[0]` for `verticlePoint[0]` to `verticlePoint[4]`

Thanks for all help!

Comment: "verticle" is not a word.  "vertical" means an up-and-down orientation or position.  But I suspect you really mean "vertex", meaning a corner or node (plural "vertices").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you want to return a different number of points depending on the shape. To do this you could for example use `std::vector<Point>` as return type... for example:

```
class Shape
{
private:
    string name;

public:
    void setName(string);
    string getName();
    virtual void setVerticlePoint() { };
    virtual std::vector<Point> getVerticlePoint();
};
```

then in square, for example, you would return a vector of 4 points...

```
std::vector<Point> Square::getVerticlePoint()
{
    return std::vector<Point>(verticlePoint, verticlePoint+4);
}
```

Comment: But my verticlePoint is of a Point verticlePoint[4] , an array, will return vector cause any issue

Comment: @user1578897: `std::vector` has a constructor that accepts two pointers: a pointer to the first element and a pointer to "past the last" element. In the example I used `verticlePoint` and `verticlePoint+4` because the member is an array and in this context the array "decades" to a pointer to the first element so the code correctly creates an `std::vector` copying the content of the array.